# How to extract both type of users count

Tags: database

I have a action table. It contain a user type admin or consumer, some actions like login, change password etc..

```
userID    actiontype       usertype
1         login            admin
2         login            consumer
3         Change Password   admin
4         Change password   admin
5         Change Password   consumer
...................
........
```

Now i have to create a result table in which i have all the count of actions by their both type of user as following table.
Result table

```
actiontype      admin       customer
login            1          1
change Password  2          1
```

How i can do this.??
sorry  for this, actually i need this .that was because of some misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create a result table using a SQL statement like below :

Create Table :

```
CREATE TABLE ResultsTable
(
ActionType varchar(50),
Count int,
UserType varchar(50)
);
```

Then insert data using the following query.

Insert Data :

```
INSERT INTO ResultsTable (ActionType, Count, UserType)
SELECT ActionType, UserType, COUNT(*) as Count
    FROM ActionTable
    GROUP BY ActionType, UserType;
```

Comment: Please take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241178/mysql-rows-to-columns Its a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the difference between `Change Password` and `change password` is just a typo and not actually in your database, you can solve that problem with a `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT actiontype, usertype, COUNT(*) as count
    FROM your_table
    GROUP BY actiontype, usertype
```

Look at [this doc](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) to find more details on the clause.

Comment: thanks for the response, ya that was a typo... i edit the question , can u plz tell me who i can solve this now.

Comment: You can solve your new requirements with an SQL query as well, however this will result in a quite a bit more complicated statement. I would personally put together the required table in your calling application (e.g. PHP). Would that be an option for you?